# Doctrine 2 : PreRemove Cascaded On All Entities

Tags: doctrine-orm

I was reading the Doctrine 2 Docs > Events > PreRemove.

> The `preRemove` event is called on every
>   entity when its passed to the
>   `EntityManager#remove()` method. It is
>   cascaded for all associations that are
>   marked as cascade delete.
>
> There are no restrictions to what
>   methods can be called inside the
>   `preRemove` event, except when the
>   remove method itself was called during
>   a flush operation.

I am trying to handle what happens to related entities.

eg. Users can ...

- Own Projects
- Collaborate in projects
- Own TodoLists
- Own Todos
- Be assigned Todos

So I want to handle all these relationships preRemove. So I did something like

```
/**
 * @PreRemove
 */
protected function onPreRemove() {
  foreach ($this->projects as $proj) {
    $proj->collaborators->remove($this);
  }
  foreach ($this->ownedTodoLists as $todoList) {
    $todoList->owner = $todoList->project->owner;
  }
  foreach ($this->ownedTodos as $todo) {
    $todo->owner = $todo->todoList->owner;
  }
  foreach ($this->assignedTodos as $todo) {
    $todo->assigned = $todo->todoList->owner;
  }
}
```

But I am thinking if this function (`preRemove`) is called for every association marked cascade delete, if my Todo, TodoList, Links are marked cascade delete, this function call won't be for them? It will waste resources and even throw an error right? `$this` will refer to entities like Todo when its run on them? How then is a good way to handle these relationships?

Or maybe I don't mark entities cascade but use functions like these to cascade delete manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with special logic (as in your provided snippet), I think this would be a pretty typical usage for the @preRemove event hook. I wouldn't use the internal cascade for any of the columns.

Comment: Hmm I am trying to convert cascade to use preRemove hooks, but I have a problem, to remove an entity I need entity manager right? But I read its not a good idea for models to have reference to entity manager? Is there a way to cascade delete in models via preRemove or is the only way via service class

Comment: Oh right, I see the dilemma you are trying to point out. But, no I don't think you need it, according to [Removing associations](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-associations.html#removing-associations). And to answer your other question, **never** use the EntityManager in an Entity.